# Using Subsitution to solve DE:

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I substituted $u=\ln(y)$, and $u'=\frac{y'}{y}$ which leads me to this:

\begin{equation}xu'-(1+x^{-2})-xe^u=0 \end{equation}

My question is can I please get hints on how to solve this? I am attempting an integrating factor and got the following two part results but I can't isolate them as a function of u, or x.

\begin{equation}\frac{M_x-N_u}{N}=\frac{1-xe^u}{(1+x^{-2})+xe^u} \end{equation}

\begin{equation}\frac{N_u-M_x}{M}=\frac{xe^u-1}{x} \end{equation}

So any hints, note not solutions, please no solutions I desire to learn how to solve this myself with hints if you understand...

Comment: This is a nonlinear ODE, it also doesn't look separable. What makes you think an explicit solution can be found?

Comment: Because it can from a problem that has a solution.

Comment: @Gregory If you undo the substitution and multiple by y, thats the original problem.

Comment: The original ODE is $x y' - (1 + x^{-2})y - x y^2 = 0$? Maybe this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

Comment: @Gregory Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the original differential equation It's [Bernoulli's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation):

$$\begin{equation}xu'-(1+x^{-2})-xe^u=0 \end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}xz'-(1+x^{-2})z=z^2x \end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}z'-(\dfrac 1x+x^{-3})z=z^2 \end{equation}$$
Where $u=\ln z$

Substitute $v=-\dfrac 1 z$:
$$v'+v \left(\dfrac 1x+\dfrac 1 {x^{3}} \right)=1$$
This is linear of first order.